# gerrit - query command with multiple numbers

Tags: gerrit

How to query gerrit with multiple gerrit numbers? for example, I have two gerrit with number 1234 and 5678, I wish use one query url to list all gerrits!

Maybe something like below:

```
http://codereview.com/a/q={1234,5678}
```

This is helpful, I can share one link to others for multiple gerrits review!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following URL in your browser:

```
http://codereview.com/q/1234+OR+5678
```

The following command gets the information you want using the REST API:

```
curl --user USER:PASS --request GET "http://codereview.com/a/changes/?q=1234+OR+5678"
```

Comment: Exactly what I want. BTW, why two command different? I mean the "q" and "a/changes" part.

Comment: The first one is the URL to access the web UI and the second one is the URL to the REST API (see more details here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html). Could you accept the answer? Thanks.